# Problems in using hsearch_r in the FIND mode

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

**I have to use two hash tables in a program and thus I am using hsearch_r**

Here I have pasted the code for my find function which tells me if an element already exists or not and if it exists it places the result in the variable *retval*

```
int is_there(char *word, struct hsearch_data *htab1){
     ENTRY e, *retval = malloc(sizeof(ENTRY)); 
     e.key = word;
     printf("%d\n", hsearch_r(e, FIND, &retval, htab1));
     return (retval);
}
```

GDB is telling me a segmentation fault is appearing somewhere here. The actual message is pasted below

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b09ed4 in __GI_hsearch_r (item=..., action=ENTER, retval=0x0, htab=0x603250) at hsearch_r.c:219
219 hsearch_r.c: No such file or directory.
```

Please, help me out.

Comment: Using malloc in a query function looks a bit odd to me. What kind of OS is that?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. The point is that hsearch_r requires me to pass a variable retval in which it can assign the return if the value is found in the hash table

Comment: Also funny: You specify as action "find" and it dumps "enter" as action. And your retval it dumps as NULL. My guess is that you use this function wrong here and that most likely, your htab1 is already a mess.

Comment: Last not least I think you should write: ``ENTRY *retval = NULL;``instead of malloc. It will write the pointer to an ENTRY within the table into your result variable.

Comment: It appears like the segfault is not happening in the C snippet you poste. If you look at the gdb message, it says that action is 'ENTER', not 'FIND'